# Is there a possibility to find multiple intents from same input

Tags: dialogflow-es

For example. "On ac and play music".

I expect two intents "Turn_ON_AC","Play_Music" must be found after we test "On ac and play music" in api.ai console window

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't invoke multiple intents at the same time.

What you can do, however, is

**Create an entity and a single intent**

1. Create an 'smart home/device action' entity. This will what the user will say to your agent.
   [image: Actions entity]
2. Create an intent that accepts this 'action' entity as a list. 
   [image: Intent with 'action' entity as a list]
3. In your fulfillment webhook code, iterate over each 'action' entities and call the necessary functions to deliver reactions and responses.

**NOTE:** This may only work on the Actions Console test window. If you're doing an action with strictly only Dialogflow, you could still try this but I am not sure if it will work.

**ADDITIONAL NOTE:** Defining multiple smart home/device actions in one go might not be the best thing to do, and frankly it might not be accepted on deployment. Make sure if you really need this functionality.

Here's the [Dialogflow documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/) if you need further help.